# Multiple child elements in XSL for each

Tags: xslt

Am using for each tag in XSL:

Scenario

Input xml

```
<root>
  <parent>
     <Child 1>
         <Child2>
              data1
              data2
              data3
                ....
                ...
         </child2>
        <Child2>
              data1
              data2
              data3
                ....
                ...
         </child2>
         <Child2>
              data1
              data2
              data3
                ....
                ...
         </child2>
</child1>
</parent>
```

When I am using for each on parent tag, in transformation file it is taking only the first occurence of child 2 repeatedly .

My requirement is, it need to take all the child two elements of child one.

Comment: Are you looking for help with an XSL transformation? Do you have any code so far, and if so would you put it in your question? Thanks.

Comment: <R3>
  <date></date>
   <name></name>
   <Adress>
     <add1>
 <name></name>
 <name1></name1>
     </add1>
     <add2>
 <name></name>
 <name1></name1>
     </add2>
     <add3>
 <name></name>
 <name1></name1>
     </add3>
    </Adress>
</R3>
<R3>
  <date></date>
   <name></name>
   <Adress>
     <add1>
 <name></name>
 <name1></name1>
     </add1>
     <add2>
 <name></name>
 <name1></name1>
     </add2>
     <add3>
 <name></name>
 <name1></name1>
     </add3>
    </Adress>
</R3>

Comment: i dont have code right now , but this is the  source xml format , , when trying to retrive r3 type using for each at target side , the out put is taking only first resords of R3 --> Adress--> add1 , but not add2 ,3 ....

Comment: OK. I suspect that if you make a start on your XSL, then people will be able to see where you are going wrong, and will be willing to advise. If you want someone to just write it for you, you may find it harder to get help.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure from the comments that you've not got well-formed input XML. You can't have 2 R3 (root) elements at the top level of the document. This could be a push in the right direction.

Which data are you actually hoping to return, and in what format?

You've also hamstrung yourself by not having a repeating group inside Adress.

If you have the option, I'd reform your XML document into something more useful, because currently it's close to unworkable.

Recommend:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AddressBook owner="" date="">
    <Address>
        <addr firstName="" secondName="">
        </addr> 
        <addr firstName="" secondName="">
        </addr>
        <addr firstName="" secondName="">
        </addr>
    </Address>
    <Address>
        <addr firstName="" secondName="">
        </addr> 
        <addr firstName="" secondName="">
        </addr>
        <addr firstName="" secondName="">
        </addr>
    </Address>
</AddressBook>
```

This way, you can iterate through the elements which are named the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/AddressBook">
        <xsl:for-each select="Address">
            <xsl:for-each select="addr">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(@firstName, ', ', @secondName)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternately, if you need to add address lines, make a repeating group inside your addr elements, and give them id's to sort by, to make sure they're in order.

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: My input xml is some what liske this

Comment: <r3>
      <r/>
      <dd>20176039</dd>
      <dt/>
      <c>SE30</c>
      <p>20170517</p>
      <c>SEK</c>
      <b>LL</b>
      <w/>
      <v>sure</v>
      <r4>
        <LI>
            <e/>
            <t>78</t>
            <g>00</g>
            <m/>
            <t/>
            <a>519</a>
         </LI>
         <LI>
            <e/>
            <t>50</t>
            <g>2611</g>
            <m/>
            <t/>
            <a>126</a>
         </LI>
         <LI>
   ..........
   </LI>
       
   
      </r4>
   </r3>
   <r3>
   ...
   </r3>